# How can I check if current ViewController is the one I am about to push?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to conditionally check if the current View is the View I am going to push? For example, on an event I want to programmatically push a SecondViewController like this:

```
if(someEvent == true) {
    if(CurrentViewController != SecondViewController) {
        // Load SecondViewController
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController as UIViewController, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        // DON'T LOAD SecondViewController
    }
 }
```

So far all this does is continually reload SecondViewController and stacks it on the hierarchy in the NavigationController. How can I effectively compare the current view to another to see if it is already loaded?

Many thanks to those who share their knowledge.

Note with Swift update the as keyword has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `visibleViewController` of `navigationController` is instance of `SecondViewController` or not.Use `isMemberOfClass` for check instance

```
if(someEvent == true) {
    if self.navigationController!.visibleViewController.isMemberOfClass(SecondViewController) {
        // DON'T LOAD SecondViewController

    }
    else {
         // Load SecondViewController
         navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController as UIViewController, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the class of self.

```
if (![self isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
    //push SecondViewController instance
}
```